# Why can't I get git to ignore a folder?

Tags: git

I'm working on a Python project with PyCharm, which includes an `.idea` folder in my project.

Because the maintainer of the project doesn't want contributors to edit the project's `.gitignore`, I added a `.gitignore_global` file to `~/{myuser}` with two lines:

```
# comment line because git has a bug where sometimes the first line is ignored
.idea/
```

I ran the command

```
git config --global core.excludesfile "C:\\Users\\{myuser}\\.gitignore_global"
```

Running `git status`, the following still appears:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .idea/
```

I tried running both of these commands:

```
git rm --cached -r .idea/
git update-index --assume-unchanged .idea/
```

The first results in an error:

```
fatal: pathspec '.idea/' did not match any files
```

The second changes nothing.

How can I get git to ignore this folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was an unnecessary space character after the directory name I wanted to ignore...

The original global excludes file:

```
#
.idea/ <--- there's a space here
```

The fixed one (no space):

```
#
.idea/
```

I swear that was the problem... Thanks everyone for your help anyway!

If this helps somebody in the future, I'm using git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

If Git isn't tracking the folder, it shouldn't appear in github. Have you tried checking the repository to make sure that it actually is uploading? If it is, try moving the .idea folder out of the project, doing a commit, and then putting it back in with the global .gitignore. If the file's changes aren't being tracked, but it's already in the repository, it will stay in the repository. It just won't be updated.

Comment: He shows that it appears under `Untracked files:` section, so it is not in repo, as it should be, the only issue seems the ignore rule doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is `git config --global core.excludesfile "C:\Users\{myuser}\.gitignore_global"` because you are using `\` and it is escape character. Try to double it.

Comment: My bad, I did use doubles.

Comment: @AvivCohn Then try to undouble them... because it depends on what are you using - cmd.exe or git bash. Just checked on my local, my .gitconfig file has `excludesfile = C:\\temp\\boo` under `[core]` section- and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

File `.gitignore` will only effect files that haven't been added already, so is `.idea/` in your repo or no?

If your `.idea/` folder is tracked yet, do `git rm -r --cached path_to_your_folder/`

Answer (score 0):

**Never ever ever** use `update-index --asume-unchanged` it will maybe appear to be doing what you want, but you are very more likely risking your files instead.

Your description most likely seems to be a problem with the `core.excludesfile` value.
Are you using Git for Windows or Cygwin Git? If the latter you might need to setup the cygwin path, not the windows path.

Alternatively you could also make your excludes in `.git/info/excludes` though then they are of course only for this repo, not for all your repos like you tried it.

You can diagnose the result also with the command `git check-ignore .idea/ --no-index -v -n` or similar.